# Почему в Android studio нельзя использовать id?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Почему в Android studio нельзя использовать id?

В итоге надо создавать id путем `id=@+id/asdasads`

Почему нельзя сделать так? `id=@id/asdasads` без плюса.

Просто когда без плюса то в XML ты видишь лишь те ID в контекстном меню которые есть в текущем макете XML.

А когда используешь + то там вываливается большой список из 100 идентификаторов. Не очень хорошо...

Кстати компилятор не дает компилировать приложение если используешь id без плюса.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что это не особенность Android Studio, а специальное соглашение.
Согласно [оффициальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html?hl=ru#idvalue) ставя `+` вы говорите специальной утилите `aapt` сгенерировать новый id в `R.java` файле. Соответственно если `+` не ставить, то этот ид не будет добавлен в файл, что повлечет ошибки компиляции.

Comment: С этим ясно. А почему тогда Студия показывает только доступные идентификаторы в текущем xml файле через id?

А если через+ то все которые есть в Проекте. Это бага такая?

Comment: @EraNewGames в одном xml файле вы можете обратиться только к тем ид, которые в нем присутствуют. А когда вводите +, то срабатывает обычное автодополнение с "глобальным контекстом".

Comment: Получается это бага такая?

Comment: @EraNewGames нет, это не баг, а стандартное поведение.